Making label same color as feature using PyQGIS
I created a rule-based symbology with the following code:
symbol_10 = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(lyr_10.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol_10)
# Definindo as regras: rótulo, expressão, cor
regras = (('Adutora 01', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 01\'', QColor(0, 255, 0)),
          ('Adutora 02', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 02\'', QColor(255, 51, 153)),
          ('Adutora 03', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 03\'', QColor(255, 102, 0)),
          ('Adutora 04', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 04\'', QColor(0, 51, 0)),
          ('Adutora 05', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 05\'', QColor(0, 0, 255)),
          ('Adutora 06', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 06\'', QColor(153, 153, 102)),
          ('Adutora 07', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 07\'', QColor(255, 153, 153)),
          ('Adutora 08', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 08\'', QColor(102, 0, 102)),
          ('Adutora 09', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 09\'', QColor(255, 255, 0)),
          ('Adutora 10', '"Adutora" LIKE \'Adutora 10\'', QColor(255, 0, 0)))

root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
for label, expression, color_name, in regras:
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
lyr_10.setRenderer(renderer)
lyr_10.triggerRepaint()
ltv = self.iface.layerTreeView()
ltv.refreshLayerSymbology(lyr_10.id())

So, the layer looks like this:

I would like the color of the labels to be the same color as the feature. How do I do this with Python? I believe with rule-based labeling. Currently I define the layer labels as follows:
adut_label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
adut_label.drawLabels = True
text_format_adut = QgsTextFormat()
text_format_adut.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
text_format_adut.setSize(12)
text_format_adut.setColor(QColor(0, 204, 255))
buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
buffer_settings.setSize(1)
buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))
text_format_adut.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
adut_label.setFormat(text_format_adut)
adut_label.isExpression = True
adut_label.fieldName = "Resultado"
adut_label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
adut_label.enabled = True
self.adutora.setLabelsEnabled(True)
self.adutora.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(adut_label))
self.adutora.triggerRepaint()

In other words, this code defines a standard color, I want this color to be defined based on the rule defined in the symbology.

To achieve this with PyQGIS, you can create a QgsPropertyCollection, set an active property passing a property enum key and a QgsProperty created from an expression ("@symbol_color"), then call setDataDefinedProperties() on your label settings.
In basic form this looks like:
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
...
props = QgsPropertyCollection()
props.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Color, QgsProperty.fromExpression("@symbol_color"))
settings.setDataDefinedProperties(props)

So your modified labeling code would look something like:
adut_label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
text_format_adut = QgsTextFormat()
text_format_adut.setFont(QFont("Arial"))
text_format_adut.setSize(12)
buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
buffer_settings.setSize(1)
buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))
text_format_adut.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
adut_label.setFormat(text_format_adut)
adut_label.fieldName = 'Resultado'
adut_label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
#Add 3 lines below #################################
props = QgsPropertyCollection()
props.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Color, QgsProperty.fromExpression("@symbol_color"))
adut_label.setDataDefinedProperties(props)
###########################################
adut_label.drawLabels = True
self.adutora.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(adut_label))
self.adutora.setLabelsEnabled(True)
self.adutora.triggerRepaint()


The colour can be taken from the symbology with a simple expression for the label color.
In the label settings go to the "Expression Builder" with

The expression @symbol_color takes the colour from the line for the label. The colour can also be manipulated darker(@symbol_color, 150) takes the colour from the line and makes it darker.
